# Can I edit the Amnesia and Psychonauts launchers to run Bumblebee?

Tags: 12.04, games, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

How do I customize the following game launchers to use bumblebee to run these games with my Nvidia card?

The terminal command is:

```
optirun game
```

The games are Amnesia the dark descent and Psychonauts, both installed through Ubuntu Sotware Centre.

In the old days you simply right-clicked on the launcher and edited the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions guys, I found an app in the software centre that does exactly what I need. Its called create launcher check it out and download it from https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/create-launcher/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately this is easy...

I assume that you have the Alacarte Menu Editor installed.

If not, please go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for:

> Alacarte

- First you go to the dash and type:

> Alacarte

- Click to open and go to Games
- Look here for Amenesia and/or Psychonauts.
- Double click on the name.
- You should see a new window popping up where you can edit the launcher to your needs.
- You should see a line of text like this:

> /home/*********/.apps/Bastion/Bastion/Bastion.bin.x86_64

- edit the command so it will use you Nvidia card.

> optirun /home/ivo/.apps/Bastion/Bastion/Bastion.bin.x86_64

- click close and close the menu editor

Start your game and have fun!

Comment: alacarte is not installed by default, not in 12.04 at least.

Comment: @geirha: ow, thats odd I always had it installed...

Comment: Yeah, since 10.10 or 11.04 or so, alacarte is no longer installed by default, so the only way to edit launchers without installing additional packages, is to edit the .desktop-files with a regular text editor. (Unless there's a way I'm not currently aware of, of course)

Comment: I that case i better ad a extra section...

Comment: you can bypass using alacarte by just dragging the launcher file into gedit.

Comment: Mmm.. i didn't know that.  But i was trying to explain it so noob friendly as possible

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am mistaken, you can do that by editing the `.sh` file in `/etc/psychonauts` and `/etc/amnesia` respectively. All you have to change is to add

```
optirun bash
```

at the beginning of the file directly after the `#!/bin/bash` line.